# Firefox mutating an <a> wrapped around a <ul> into a big mess of duplicated <a>

Tags: firefox, xhtml

Chrome, IE8, Safari, and Opera all act the way I would expect, but Firefox is turning this...

```
<a class="header" href="a_link.html">
    <ul class="header">
        <li class="price">$17,880</li>
        <li class="year">2006</li>
        <li class="make">Honda</li>
        <li class="model">Civic</li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

...into this...

```
<a href="a_link.html" class="header"></a>
    <ul class="header">
    <a href="a_link.html" class="header"></a>
    <li class="price"><a href="a_link.html" class="header">$17,880</a></li>
    <a href="a_link.html" class="header"></a>
    <li class="year"><a href="a_link.html" class="header">2006</a></li>
    <a href="a_link.html" class="header"></a>
    <li class="make"><a href="a_link.html" class="header">Honda</a></li>
    <a href="a_link.html" class="header"></a>
    <li class="model"><a href="a_link.html" class="header">Civic</a></li>
    <a href="a_link.html" class="header"></a></ul>
<a href="a_link.html" class="header"></a>
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Cheers

Comment: I'm not so sure I would expect 'A' to work like that (around non-inline elements), although the Firefox case doesn't seem a bit ... obtuse. It appears to be wrapping all the *inline* elements inside of it to the tightest scope it can (I would expect it to just "not work" instead of trying to "fix" it, honestly).

Comment: This is because anchor tags (inline) cannot contain block level elements such as li and ul (see html standards)

Comment: @pst, firefox does a TON of assuming and "fixing"

Comment: @Kevin Peno Oh the joys of modern browsers...

Comment: My only question to you is: This matters because....? Does it break functionality? Does it cause odd artifacts on the page? What's the problem with it? It's only internal to Firefox.

Comment: @Kevin - it changes the styling a lot

Comment: How? Perhaps you should post the styles that are affecting the poor output by firefox.

Comment: @dialer How do I accept your comment as an answer? If there isn't a way, feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Oh yea, and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dialer is correct. But just a supplementary note: using a doctype of html should fix this - it will turn the page into html 5 standards which allows the use of anchors in this way.

This may be undesirable for other reasons, but thought I'd mention it!

Comment: Do you have a link to the part in the standard that allows a backward incompatible change like this to happen?

Comment: Browsers only care about Standards Mode and Quirks Mode. They don't care what the particular standard relating to the Doctype actually means. Using an HTML 5 Doctype doesn't cause a browser to start supporting HTML 5.

Comment: @Kevin — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element — now has a Transparent content model.

Comment: @David, thanks for the lesson on the transparent content model.

Comment: @David ah yes, good point! I made assumptions of html5 support based on it being a firefox issue.